# Convert DateTime to Date string "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

How can I convert DateTime to a string "dd/mm/yyyy"?
The problem I'm having is that since the conversion is inside a linq expression I must use `DateTime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`. However, the date keeps coming back with the time--`1/21/1999 12:00:00 AM`. How can I remove the time part directly in this query?

```
_unitOfWork.PlacementFinancialViewRepository.GetEfs07Placements()
  .Where(x => x.FiscalYear == fiscalYear && x.ResponsibleSauId == responsibleDistrictId)
  .ToList()
  .Select(x => new Efs07PlacementModel
   {
     PlacementStartDate = x.PlacementStartDate == null 
       ? null 
       : x.PlacementStartDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
     PlacementEndDate = x.PlacementEndDate == null 
       ? null 
       : x.PlacementEndDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: In your DB, the data type of `PlacementStartDate` may be `DateTime` thats why

Comment: Yes it is, but how can convert it? I guess I could just change the db datatype...

Comment: You may convert it to "MM/dd/yyyy" at the time you are displaying the dates - not there while you are creating a List

Comment: A DateTime variable is composed of a Date AND Time. You can't get rid of the time part. But this is a bit strange. How can you assign the result of a ToString to a DateTime variable? Did you get some error here?

Comment: @Steve: PlacementStartDate and PlacementEndDate  are strings but x.PlacementStartDate  and x.PlacementEndDate  are datetimes.

Comment: Then where do you see the time part? It cannot be on the two receiving strings because you ask explicitely for MM/dd/yyyy format

Comment: @Steve: The time part is showing in the Ui. It must be because I'm using Datetime.Value

Answer (score 0):

You may leave the List creation as is, with no conversion to the required format. So you may use you code as:

```
_unitOfWork.PlacementFinancialViewRepository.GetEfs07Placements().Where(x => x.FiscalYear == fiscalYear && x.ResponsibleSauId == responsibleDistrictId)
.ToList()
.Select(x => new Efs07PlacementModel
{
    PlacementStartDate = x.PlacementStartDate == null ? null : x.PlacementStartDate,
    PlacementEndDate = x.PlacementEndDate == null ? null : x.PlacementEndDate
}).ToList();
```

Then you can then convert the `PlacementStartDate` to your required format at the time yo uare displaying it on a View/UI.

Comment: I'd rather do it in this query, if possible

Comment: In your `Efs07PlacementModel` you may use some `Annotations` to set the `DisplayAs` attribute to your required format.

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime object is a count of milliseconds that have elapsed since midnight, January 1, 0001 AD. You are actually queering a number and automatically casting it into a DateTime (essentially). If your database has been saving the day but not the time, it will result in those milliseconds being set to 0. This is because you have just simply not added the milliseconds that represent the time of day.

You can, as others have stated, ignore the time or ensure that it is always set to midnight. Then in your displays set the format.

I would suggest doing this in your model object with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

This way you can use `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DateTimeObject)` in your view and that sets your formatting.

**Update:**

In addition, you can add the attribute `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` in your object model. This will not change how the data is stored in the database by EF6, just how it is displayed by default. Some other ORM's may not behave this way so please read up on your ORM.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime PlacementStartDate { get; set; }
```